# Won't Boot After Removing Sound-theme-freedesktop freedesktop.org from Linux mint 20.3

Tags: linux, audio, backup, theme, restore

I removed sound-theme-freedesktop from linux mint 20.3 software manager because I thought it was unnecessary sounds that I don't need or use. After doing so, I rebooted and the system just hangs on the Linux Mint logo during boot. If I hit ESC to see the terminal system load, it is doing a series of hard drive and driver check over and over. I've let it go for 45 min and it just cycles over.

What can I do? Is there any way to add sound-theme-freedesktop back?

I tried to restore from live usb but it couldn't find any timeshift files that I setup to backup from a USB or on the main system itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide the command you used to remove `sound-theme-freedesktop`?

Comment: Hi, I used the Linux Mint software manager and clicked remove.